# Updating last DB entry with Symfony & Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

Firstly please excuse more poor code, I'm relatively new to PHP/Symfony/Doctrine.

What I am trying to achieve with the below code is as follows, I need to update the 'Notification_ID' field of the last DB entry. Now the top half of the code is retrieving the ID of the last DB entry that I can then refer to with the second half of the code which will then add the Notification Id (which comes in via POST) to that DB entry.

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT z.id
        FROM AppBundle:ZeusUsers z
        ORDER BY z.id DESC');
    $query->setMaxResults(1);
    $id = $query->getSingleScalarResult();

    $notificationid = $this->getRequest()->get("notification_id");

    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'UPDATE AppBundle:ZeusUsers z
        SET z.notification_id = $notificationid
        WHERE z.id = $id');
    $query->execute();

    $em->flush();

    return new Response("", 200, array("content-type"=>"text/html"));
```

**CODE UPDATED ABOVE**

This is now returning the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 57: Error: Expected Literal, got '$' (500 Internal Server Error)
```

<del>It seems to be having issues with it referencing variables from outside the query, any ideas?</del>

How would I do the second query in native Symfony instead of using a query function like I am?

Comment: Is this all in the same action? Please post the entire code for the action. It appears to me that every time you do `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` you'll be getting a new instance of the entity manager and will be wiping out the changes you made. If you are doing this all in the same action you only need to get the manager once.

Comment: That is the entire action.

Comment: Only keep the top `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` and remove the other ones.

Comment: Just noticed you are doing this with SQL queries. You must `$query->execute();` after you create the query. I would recommend spending some time learning how to move away from using queries like this to using the native Symfony objects and entities

Comment: Deleted the last 2 `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` and added the `$query->execute();` after the second query but all I'm getting now is _[Syntax Error] line 0, col 57: Error: Expected Literal, got &#039;$&#039; (500 Internal Server Error)_. I know this isn't the most efficient code and I should use Symfony objects but I just need a quick fix.

Comment: Please post a code update.

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: You are using createQuery which allows you to use normal query in Doctrine. hmn... and there is a $query->execute(), this should UPDATE the DB. Have you checked your db creds? maybe look at the mysql query log?

Comment: Just updated the error above.

Comment: Check your logs and find the actually query

Comment: I can't with my current hosting service

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it functioning with the following:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT z.id
    FROM AppBundle:ZeusUsers z
    ORDER BY z.id DESC');
$query->setMaxResults(1);
$id = $query->getSingleScalarResult();

$notification_id = $this->getRequest()->get("notification_id");

$query1 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$q = $query1->update('AppBundle:ZeusUsers', 'z')
    ->set('z.notification_id', '?1')
    ->where('z.id = ?2')
    ->setParameter(1, $notification_id)
    ->setParameter(2, $id)
    ->getQuery();
$p = $q->execute();

return new Response("", 200, array("content-type"=>"text/html"));
```

Thank you for those who assisted me.